# Force Jetpack Compose to update layout on orientation change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

While the compose function is called again on orientation change and new values for screen size are measured the composeables on screen are using the old values from before orientation change until there is some user input.
How can I force compose to use the new values for screen size?

Answer (score 0):

I got probably the wrong approach. The solution is to make the concerned values stateful.